# Differenza tra opportuno, appropriato e adatto

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

> Scegli il vestito più opportuno/appropriato/adatto per una festa del genere

Direi che in questa frase sono intercambiabili, ma quando si parla di soggetti animati (persone) trovo difficile usarli tutti e tre, ad eccezione di adatto.
Es.: "Sono adatto per queste cose"

Non suonerebbe strano dire "opportuno" o "appropriato" in quest'ultima frase? Non stonerebbe?

Comment: Ho limato qualche refuso, @Nakamura, ma se rileggi quello che scrivi prima di mandarlo non lo deve fare qualcun altro! :)

Comment: Scusa. Starò più attento!

Comment: "Sono appropriato per queste cose" stonerebbe. Ma "È la persona più appropriata per questo lavoro" non stonerebbe così tanto. E "persona poco opportuna" lo trovi persino sulla Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/opportuno_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)

Comment: @user3664452: Poco opportuno nel senso di adatto? Tipo "è una persona poco opportuna per questo tipo di mestiere"

Comment: @Nakamura: più che inadatto nel senso di fuori luogo (in senso figurato) volevo dire poco opportuno nel senso di importuno, molesto (cfr. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/importunare)

Answer (score 2):

**Appropriato** viene usato per indicare qualcosa che sta bene con  lo scopo o con il contesto di cui si parla e in alcuni casi ne evidenzia la necessità.

> È **appropriato** venire vestiti eleganti ad un matrimonio.

**Adatto** indica qualcosa che risponde ad un determinato scopo o ad un determinato contesto, senza però implicarne la necessità.

> È la persona più **adatta** a quel lavoro, vista la sua propensione ad interagire con il pubblico.

**Opportuno** ha lo stesso significato di appropriato ma ne evidenzia la necessità.

> È **opportuno** dare del lei al proprio datore di lavoro.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Sarebbe corretto dire "È la persona più appropriata a quel lavoro ..."? Non vedo segni di necessità qui, ma la tua risposta dice che "appropriato" li esprime solo a volte.

Comment: Penso che sia più corretto dire che la persona è "adatta" rispetto ad "appropriata".

Answer (score 0):

Non so se esiste una regola generale, ma "adatto" è sicuramente la scelta più frequente, soprattutto considerando il parlato.

Ci sono però delle eccezioni, ad [esempio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/opportuno/) "Un visitatore poco opportuno" suona corretto sia nel parlato sia nello scritto.